# The work of elimination is cut in half when $A$ is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra

I am going through the book "Gilbert Strang - Introduction to Linear Algebra, Third Edition (2003)" and as I was working through the chapter of transpose matrices and solving systems of linear equations, I got stuck at this one particular sentence.
[image: ss]
What does the author mean by 'smaller matrices', and how do they stay the same as elimination proceeds.
I tried doing the process by hand, chose a 3x3 symmetric matrix, and I didn't see the symmetry until the very end: $A = LDU = LDL^T$
Also, as you may notice, in the end he even says the work of elimination is cut in half. I really don't see this.

Comment: After one step of Gaussian elimination on an $n \times n$ matrix 
$M_{n}$, you get a matrix of the form 
$$\pmatrix{
a_{1} & a_{2} & \ldots & a_{n} \\
0 &   &        &  \\
\vdots &   & M_{n-1}&  \\
0 & & & \\
}$$
where $M_{n-1}$ is an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ (smaller) matrix. 
I think these are the `smaller matrices' which are all symmetric.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Thanks a ton